# Merge unallocated partition into my mounted partition

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

[image: Gparted Image]

As you can see, I am mounted on `/dev/nvme0n1p5`. Gparted does not allow me to merge the unallocated partition (51.94GB) into the extended partition (i.e. mounted partition) using `Move/Resize` action. I thought I could use the GRUB, but not sure how to do it. What do you suggestion. As this unallocated is quite a lot of space, I would be interested in using it inside the mounted one. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The unallocated space must *follow* a partition to be able to merge it
into the partition.

Move `nvme0n1p5` upward over the unallocated space, and it will then move
after the partition.

Now you can merge the unallocated space.

Take full backups, as partition work is dangerous in case of error.